# Subharmonic functions and monotonically increasing integrals

Tags: lebesgue-integral, harmonic-functions

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and $f : U \to \mathbb{R}\cup\{ - \infty\}$ be a subharmonic function. Define $\varphi(r) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(a + re^{i\theta}) \ d\theta$. Show that $\varphi$ is monotonically increaing by first showing that it is monotonically increasing if $f$ is a $C^2$ function and then proceed to the general case where we assume no differentiability of $f$.

Note the definition I'm using for subharmonic is that it is upper-semicontinuous and satisfies the sub-mean-value property.

It is easy to show in the $C^2$ case - just apply Green's theorem and use the fact that subharmonicity is equivalent to the Laplacian being non-negative when the function is $C^2$. I'm struggling with the general case. I thought to do the following:

We want to show that for $f$ subharmonic and $r_1 < r_2$ then $\varphi(r_1) \leq \varphi(r_2)$. If $f_{\epsilon}$ denotes $f$ mollified with the standard mollifier then for each $\epsilon > 0$ we have that $f$ is smooth and subharmonic so the $C^2$ case applies and we get that $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f_{\epsilon}(a + r_2e^{i\theta}) - f_{\epsilon}(a + r_1 e^{i\theta}) \ d\theta \geq 0$. What I really would like to do is take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ of the above and interchange the integral and limit but I can't quite figure out how to justify it (that is, make sure the hypotheses of the dominated convergence theorem hold) while still making sure that the inequality is maintained (i.e., without taking absolute values).

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof of sub mean value property and the definition via comparison principle are equivalent?

Comment: If what you mean by the comparison principle is that if you take a disc and a harmonic function which is greater than or equal to the subharmonic function on the boundary then the harmonic function is greater than or equal to the subharmonic function everywhere on the disc then yes I am familiar with that.

Comment: Yes there's a direct proof of the monotonicity of spherical averages using this comparison definition of subharmonic function. But if you are looking for a proof of $f_\epsilon \searrow f$ monotonically then you may look at [Ransford](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Potential_Theory_in_the_Complex_Plane.html?id=bukn-Rs-t3sC&redir_esc=y) Theorem 2.7.2 to justify the passage of limit by monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Do you know the direct proof you mention?

Comment: 'kay .. I'll try to write it down as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, $f$ is u.s.c it is infimum of a monotone decreasing sequence $\{g_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of continuous functions, that is $g_k \searrow f$ monotonically. Then we kave $f \le g_k$ on $\partial D_{r_2}(a)$ and consider the unique harmonic function $h$ in $D_{r_2}(a)$ s.t., $h\rvert_{\partial D_{r_2}(a)} = g_k$. Then by mean value property we have $\displaystyle h(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} g_k(a + r_2e^{i\theta})\,d\theta$.

Also by comparison theorem for subharmonic functions we know $f \le h$ in $D_{r_2}(a)$ and in particular for $r_1 < r_2$ we have $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(a + r_1e^{i\theta})\,d\theta \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} h(a + r_1e^{i\theta})\,d\theta = h(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} g_k(a + r_2e^{i\theta})\,d\theta.$$

Now letting $k \to \infty$ by monotone convergence theorem we have the desired conclusion $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(a + r_1e^{i\theta})\,d\theta \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(a + r_2e^{i\theta})\,d\theta, \forall \, r_1 < r_2.$$